# Retrieving a node solely based on its Tag

Tags: opc-ua

A customer has implemented an OPC-UA server and has provided some documentation for us to access it. The only information we have is the endpoint to contact the server at and the tags that the data points are linked to.

I have to implement a client without having access to the server to test it with. Is this enough information to go by? I imagine we would at least need some namespace uri. From what I understand, in order to use a function such as `translateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` I would also need to know some namespace ID's.

For instance, in python-opcua it would be something like:

`mynode = client.uaclient.translate_browsepaths_to_nodeids(ua.QualifiedName("StaticData", 3))` (which somehow is not working but that's another question)

It doesn't help that the client examples I find somehow all use hardcoded namespace ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TranslateBrowsePathToNodeIds is *generally* used when programming against type definitions where you know what the path of BrowseNames will be because they are defined by the type definition of each node in the path.

If this doesn't sound like your situation then you should push back for the documentation to include the NodeIds of all the Nodes you need to access.

Comment: My knowledge in the OPC-UA world is limited to this particular project, but I imagine that they had a reason to supply only the tags instead of just the node id's - unless they were only aiming at helping people understand the data when viewed through a GUI. Also it was my understanding that node id's (and in some cases, name space id's?) aren't necessarily static and can change. Would you concur then that just knowledge of the tags is insufficient? The tags themselves have a format of e.g. "Brand.Machine.Sensor.Temp".

Comment: Trying to draw conclusion from the tag names would only be guessing. Maybe TranslateBrowsePaths will work, or maybe you can guess the NodeId, but I think you need more information. While a Node can be added or removed from a server, the NodeId for a given Node is supposed to be persistent, even across restarts.